# Ping and mDNS over WireGuard not working

Tags: vpn, ping, wireguard, mdns

When running through WireGuard VPN tunnel from outside the network, I can access machines inside directly via IP. For example, hitting IP of PiHole box in a browser returns the PiHole UI. I can also access the internet fine.

When issuing a ping command to that same IP address through WireGuard results in a “no route to host” error. Same applies to pinging the router’s IP. When inside network on WiFi, running ping gets a response for both.

Ultimately trying to troubleshoot why mDNS packets aren’t making it to and from the device on VPN. There’s a mDNS reflector on the router, specifically enabled for WireGuard interface, so should be making it across the tunnel. The ping and mDNS issues could be related.

Where should I be looking to troubleshoot?

Comment: *Where should I be looking to troubleshoot?* - your wireguard configuration

Comment: The ping could be blocked by a firewall: if the same IP destination works with TCP (HTTPS...) and not ICMP, This can't be a routing problem, or you didn't provide everything (like iptables/nftables port redirection etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Wireguard connections do not support multicast by default (you may be able to force it on after the link is created), so even with a mDNS reflector it's not going to see the mDNS requests over the tunnel.

EDIT:

You can enable it after the link is up, but it needs to be done at both ends e.g. with

```
PostUp = ip l set wg0 multicast on
```